# How to underline text and how to hide table border in Apache POI

Tags: java, apache-poi

I have got two doubts. I have created a word document with a table in Apache POI.

1. How to underline text?

   XWPFRun rh = para.createRun();
    rh.setText("Added to Watchlist");
    rh.setBold(true);

   I have created a text content and I have bolded it. How to underline it? I found a function `rh.setUnderline`
   What is the parameter for `rh.setUnderline()`
2. how to hide table border in Apache POI?

   `XWPFTable table = doc.createTable(5, 5);`

   I want to hide the border of this table? How do I it?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You could try:

```
table.getCTTbl().getTblPr().unsetTblBorders();
```

Comment: This command give the below error:

java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.store.Xobj.removeElement(Xobj.java:2188)
 at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.store.Xobj.remove_element(Xobj.java:2218)
 at org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.impl.CTTblPrBaseImpl.unsetTblBorders(Unknown Source)

Comment: Not sure what version you were using, but this does not remove borders for my version of apache poi :-(  It did seem to make them thinner, so it might be the table borders got removed, but still need to remove the cell borders.

Answer (score 0):

For the first question, `rh.setUnderline(UnderlinePatterns.SINGLE)` or any other parameters depending on the underline style will work.

Answer (score 0):

This is answer for how to set underline in text. You can try this:

```
    XWPFParagraph subparacenter = document.createParagraph();
    subparacenter.setAlignment(ParagraphAlignment.LEFT);
    **XWPFRun subcenterRun = subparacenter.createRun();**

    subcenterRun.setUnderline(UnderlinePatterns.SINGLE);    
    subcenterRun.setFontSize(11);
```